# Made with Marmalade SDK games don't work in Mac App Store

Tags: mac-app-store, marmalade, application-loader

We made game with Marmalade SDK for Mac OS X platform. The game works well for us and for our QA team. But after submitting it to the Mac App Store, using the Application Loader, we got a rejection because the game crashes on launch. Investigating crash logs we found out that the Marmalade loader couldn't load .s86 executable file on launch. And after few resubmitting our application to the Mac App Store we got the following two errors:
"Invalid .s86 file"
"Couldn't load .s86 file"

We can reproduce the same crashes and the same error massages only if we explicitly damaging .s86 file. For example by editing this binary .s86 file in a text editor.

So, my questions are: 
Does Application Loader make any changes with files inside our application?
And does anybody have an experience of publishing application made with Marmalade to Mac App Store?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

We used: 
Marmalade SDK 6.3, Xcode 4.5, Application Loader 2.8, 2.9

Comment: Have you posted this question to devnet.madewithmarmalade.com too? You will get better response there.

Comment: Yes, I posted there too. Here is the [link](https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/16954/made-with-marmalade-sdk-games-dont-work-in-mac-app.html). And I did even more, I created a ticket in Marmalade Pro/Plus support, but they just suggested me to remove spaces from game name and to try SysAppExeX86 option in .icf. But it didn't help me. And they just don't responding me now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Marmalade and Apple have depreciated a number of APIs recently that will probably cause your game to be rejected or at least not behave. Marmalade 7.2 due to be released in a few days will resolve the issue.

Please raise another support ticket if you require additional information and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: The problem was solved. It was with permission settings. I've wrote about it on marmalade dev forum. And about deprecation API (QT API for example) it was done by my request in ticket to support. Now I already have a hot fix for QT issue even before 7.2 release.